# Oracle SQL select max "for each" row

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to find a way to select the rows with the highest value for each user in a table. Unless I'm misunderstanding, I can't simply group by each row

For example, say I have a query like this currently:

```
select u.userid, p.region, count(u.userid) count
from userTable u join purchasesTable p on u.userid = p.userid
group by (u.userid, p.region)
```

and it gives a result like this currently:

```
id          Region     COUNT
---------- ----------- ----------
1           East       1
2           West       1
3           North      1
1           North      2
2           East       3
3           West       4
```

I want to filter the results to show the region with the most purchases for each user (NOT the region or user with the most purchases overall).

```
id          Region     COUNT
---------- ----------- ----------
1           North      2
2           East       3
3           West       4
```

I can't make the group by clause only contain the userid, because I want to include the region. But I don't want the region column to be factored in to the decision. I thought about wrapping this in another query which then takes the max values, but I haven't had any success with that approach. I also thought about using the distinct keyword, but that wouldn't solve this problem either.

If somebody could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What if there are two regions tied for the highest count for the same id? Do you need to return all those rows, or just one of them - and if "just one", which one? For example, assume for a new id, say `id=4`, the highest count is 4, and this count of 4 is the same for `East` and `North`. What should the output show for `id=4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `row_number()`:

```
select userid, region, cnt
from (select p.userid, p.region, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by p.userid order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from purchasesTable p 
      group by p.userid, p.region
     ) ur
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  I removed the `join` from the query.  For your query as stated, it is not necessary, because `p.userid` is the same as `u.userid`.  Of course, if you wanted other information from the `usersTable`, then you would need the `join` to get it.

Answer (score 0):

try this, your query is inside `from` clausole:

```
select
id,region,max(count_)
from
(
    select u.userid, p.region, count(u.userid) count as count_
    from userTable u join purchasesTable p on u.userid = p.userid
    group by (u.userid, p.region)
) exe
group by id,region
```

Comment: I tried this actually, but unfortunately it doesn't change the output at all. I think it's because there are no duplicate entries between the (id,region) group. Like if there were multiple entries with the same id/region, then I think it would filter those out. But I don't think it will do the trick here.